# Efficiently Iterating through image in Javascript

Tags: javascript, image-processing, canvas, multidimensional-array, web-worker

I am doing some image processing project in JavaScript where i need to iterate through each image pixels and do some other processing to achieve my target.
I am using canvas to get an image pixels data array.
For small images, like 500x300 px in dimensions, its working fine and taking acceptable time. But for large images, like 3000x3000 px in dimensions, the iteration process is becoming a bottleneck and taking a huge time, like 10-12 seconds.

So is there any method or trick which could be used to reduce the time used in the iteration steps?

Here is what I am thinking about: I am trying to use parallel web workers(let it be 4) to iterate through equal parts of the image data: (eg. `0-[len/4]`, `[len/4]+1-[len/2]`, `[len/2]+1 - [len*3/4]`, `[len*3/4]+1 - len`) where `len`is the size of the image data array.

I doubt this approach will be more time efficient since Javascript is single threaded.

```
 function rgb2grey(pix,offset){
        return (0.2989*pix[offset] + 0.5870*pix[offset+1] + 
    0.1140*pix[offset+2]);

}

function imgcompare(fileData1,fileData2,targetpix){
        var len = pix.length;
        for (var j = 0; j <len; j+=4) {
                var grey1 = rgb2grey(fileData1,j);
            var grey2 = rgb2grey(fileData2,j);
            if(grey1!=grey2){
                targetpix[j] = 255;
                targetpix[j+1] = targetpix[j+2] = 0;
            }
            else{
                targetpix[j] = fileData1[j];
                targetpix[j+1] = fileData1[j+1];
                targetpix[j+2] = fileData1[j+2];
            }       
            targetpix[j+3] = fileData1[j+3];
        }
}
```

Comment: A loop with 90000 iterations really isn't that impressive. I think the possible performance gain is in what you actually do _in_ the loop. Post your code ([mcve]), maybe there's something wrong in there.

Comment: You should show your code so we can at least see what you are working with - and even help you.

Comment: I am simply comparing pixel values of two images, so i don't think there is any chance of improvement.

Comment: @flamelite is it important to know *where* the images differ, or only *if* they differ? (the latter can be done in more efficient ways)

Comment: In all cases, try to tail call optimize the loop. Web workers will allow you to delegate work to other threads, or use something like [gpujs](http://gpu.rocks/) ; if this is done server-side, consider maybe delegating this work to other languages with better parallel programming support.

Comment: @flamelite: Please post your code. If all you're doing is comparing the data, it can not take that long. Maybe there's a different heavy operation that you're running every iteration of the loop, for example.

Comment: @TimothyGroote i told that point in reference to operation happening inside loop. As i have mentioned in my question i m looking for some alternative in loop iteration process.

Comment: @Cerbrus Where does 90000 come from?

Comment: @Teemu from missing a `0` in `3000^2` -.-

Comment: @TimothyGroote yeah its important know the location of difference so that they can be marked by some other color.

Comment: @flamelite: If you don't post an [mcve], we can not help you. the problem is most likely not with the fact you're iterating over every pixel, but with what you're doing each iteration.

Comment: @SumiStraessle i have to do this project in frontend only

Comment: @flamelite Then I'd avoid going berserk with web workers and gpujs since it can slow down the user's computer dramatically ; using only one, or a maximum of two, web workers can help alleviate load on the main ui thread and, thus, improve UX. However, I'd try and make some sort of queuing mechanism so as not to work on too many images at once. You need to avoid blocking the user's GUI (think promises here, for example).

Comment: I have added code. Actully muy original soucecode is very large and much complicated so i added a simpler version of my source code to summarize my problem.

Comment: @Sumi promises can also be good option here but i don't think it will be different than using web workers.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. What does `rgb2grey` contain? Is there any other code in your loop? The point of this question is that there's something _in_ the loop that might be slowing down the application. If you remove code, you may have removed the problem.

Comment: @flamelite promises were meant to manage the queuing mechanism suggested.

Comment: @Cerbrus rgb2grey is to convert rgb color data to gray value.

Comment: @cerbus no for this particular function imgcompare there is not other part

Comment: Create an Uint32Array view of your imageData.data. You'll avoid the need to access all 4 channels separately.

Comment: I'd also avoid computing the array length on each iteration, do this instead :  `for (var j=0, jmax=pix.length ; j<jmax ; j+=4) { ... }`

Comment: Make sure rgb2grey returns an integer value using either Math.floor() or add a shift-0 OP at the end (both the browser optimizer and the compare will be happy for this). Compare strict using !==. For webworkers you could use SharedTypedArrays (newer browsers only). Convert to Uint32Array when iterating (shift + and mask are generally faster than looking up an larger array). Depending on how accurate you need the luma (grey) value to be you could also convert it to full integer or average (you would anyway want to use rec.709 for accuracy).

Comment: *) should be `SharedArrayBuffer` (not `SharedTypedArray`)

Comment: @SumiStraessle That precomputed array length does not improve the performance as the optimiser knows it's a fixed value and thus does not need to get the value each iteration.

Comment: @Blindman67 It's a good thing the optimizer makes our life easier ; precomputing array length and doing `++i` vs `i++` are considered best practices, to the best of my knowledge ; thus, IMHO, this is the advisable thing to do, even if the interpreter / compiler puts optimization and safeguards for us.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### 2D canvas API and GPU assisted image processing.

The canvas 2D API provides a powerful set of GPU assisted composite operations. Many times they can replace slow pixel by pixel operations done via Javascript and reading pixel via getImageData.

Many times this can make the processing a realtime solution for video or animations, and it also has the advantage that it can process tainted canvases that otherwise would be impossible using any other method.

#### The OP's processing via GPU assisted compositing

In the case the question example there is some room for optimisation by using the canvas 2D composite operations. This will utilise the GPU to do the per-pixel math for you though you will have to create two additional canvases.

To mark pixels with red that are different between two images.

- Create two copies
- Get difference in pixels using comp "difference"
- Make difference BW using comp "saturation"
- Max the difference by rendering difference over itself using comp "lighter"
- Invert the difference using comp difference and rendering a white rect over it
- Multiply imageA's copy with the inverted difference using comp "multiply"
- Invert the mask again
- Set channels Green and Blue to zero in the difference canvas using comp "multiply".
- Add the mask to the original masked image using comp "lighter".

#### Demo

The demo loads two images and then marks the differences between the two images in red (`"#F00"`) using the method outlined above.

```js
// creates a copy of an image as a canvas
function copyImage(image) {
    const copy = document.createElement("canvas");
    copy.width = image.width;
    copy.height = image.height;
    copy.ctx = copy.getContext("2d"); // add context to the copy for easy reference
    copy.ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
    return copy;
}
// returns a new canvas containing the difference between imageA and imageB
function getDifference(imageA, imageB) {
    const dif = copyImage(imageA);
    dif.ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "difference";
    dif.ctx.drawImage(imageB, 0, 0);
    return dif;
}
// Desaturates the image to black and white
function makeBW(image) { // color is a valid CSS color
    image.ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "saturation";
    image.ctx.fillStyle = "#FFF";
    image.ctx.fillRect(0, 0, image.width, image.height);
    return image;
}
// Will set all channels to max (255) if over value 0
function maxChannels(image) { 
    var i = 8; // 8 times as the channel values are doubled each draw Thus 1 * 2^8 to get 255
    image.ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "lighter";
    while (i--) {
        image.ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0)
    }
    return image;
}
// Inverts the color channels resultRGB = 255 - imageRGB
function invert(image) {
    image.ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "difference";
    image.ctx.fillStyle = "#FFF";
    image.ctx.fillRect(0, 0, image.width, image.height);
    return image;
}
// Keeps pixels that are white in mask and sets pixels to black if black in mask.
function maskOut(image, mask) {
    image.ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "multiply";
    image.ctx.drawImage(mask, 0, 0);
    return image;
}
// Adds the channels from imageB to imageA. resultRGB = imageA_RGB + imageB_RGB
function addChannels(imageA, imageB) { // adds imageB channels to imageA channels
    imageA.ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "lighter";
    imageA.ctx.drawImage(imageB, 0, 0);
    return imageA;
}
// zeros channels is its flag (red, green, blue) is true
function zeroChannels(image, red, green, blue) { // set channels to zero to true
    image.ctx.fillStyle = `#${red ? "0" : "F"}${green ? "0" : "F"}${blue ? "0" : "F"}`;
    image.ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "multiply";
    image.ctx.fillRect(0, 0, image.width, image.height);
    return image;
}
// returns a new canvas that is a copy of imageA with pixels that are different from imageB marked in red.
function markDifference(imageA, imageB) {
    const result = copyImage(imageA);
    const mask = invert( maxChannels( makeBW(  getDifference(imageA, imageB))));
    maskOut(result, mask);
    return addChannels(result,zeroChannels(invert(mask), false, true, true));
}
const images = [
    "https://i.stack.imgur.com/ImeHB.jpg",
    "https://i.stack.imgur.com/UrrnL.jpg"
  ];
  var imageCount = 0;
  function onImageLoad(){
    imageCount += 1;
    if(imageCount === 2){
      addImageToPage(markDifference(images[0],images[1]));
      addImageToPage(images[0]);
      addImageToPage(images[1]);
       
    }
  }
  function addImageToPage(image){
    image.className = "images";
    document.body.appendChild(image);
  }
  images.forEach((url, i) => {
    images[i] = new Image;
    images[i].src = url;
    images[i].onload = onImageLoad;
  });
```

```css
.images {
  width : 100%;
}
```

Comment: Where did these people go? Or was the sea frozen? Anyway yes good idea to show a completely alternative way of doing *almost* the same.

Comment: Thanks man. Your answer has given me a different approach to solve my problem, and also it inspired to explore more into canvas.

Comment: @Blindman67 by running your sample example i can see that in difference image some portions which are not difference are also marked as red eg. extra areas marked as red around the kid.

Comment: @flamelite I have checked the result programmatically and it is correct. If you are comparing it to  your question you will have pixels that are not marked different because you are comparing gray scale eg (without the weights) #F00 = #0F0 = #00F (red is the same as green and blue) With the weights the same thing will happen. If you want to compare gray scale use the function `makeBW` and set the `image.ctx.fillStyle = "rgb("+(255 * 0.2989 | 0) + ","+(255 * 0.5870 | 0) + ","+(255 * 0.1140 | 0) + ")"` this will reduce the dynamic range and making more pixels the same.

Comment: @flamelite Forgot to say, convert to weighted BW as the first step.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Javascript Image Processing Framework like [MarvinJ](http://www.marvinj.org). The snippet below demonstrates how to iterate through pixels to implement a color threshold algorithm.

```js
var canvas1 = document.getElementById("canvas1");
var canvas2 = document.getElementById("canvas2");

image = new MarvinImage();
image.load("https://i.imgur.com/gaW8OeL.jpg", imageLoaded);


function imageLoaded(){
  image.draw(canvas1);
  var threshold=200;
  for(var y=0; y<image.getHeight(); y++){
    for(var x=0; x<image.getWidth(); x++){
       var r = image.getIntComponent0(x,y);
       var g = image.getIntComponent1(x,y);
       var b = image.getIntComponent2(x,y);
       
       if(r <= threshold && g <= threshold && b <= threshold){
         image.setIntColor(x, y, 0xFF000000);
       } else{
         image.setIntColor(x, y, 0xFFFFFFFF);
       }
     }
   }
   
   image.draw(canvas2);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.marvinj.org/releases/marvinj-0.7.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas1" width="200" height="200"></canvas>
<canvas id="canvas2" width="200" height="200"></canvas>
```